# Correspondence between Lie algebra addition and Lie group product?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Does a Lie group product such as $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ translate to a sum of Lie algebras, and vice-versa? For example, consider the Lie algebra $su(2)+isu(2)$. When exponentiated, we get

$$
e^{su(2)+isu(2)} = e^{su(2)}e^{isu(2)} = SU(2)\times SU(2)
$$

where the $i$ is added, I guess, to guaranteed commutativity of the two terms $su(2)$ and therefore split them out of the exponentiation?

Comment: If you mean *direct* sums and *direct* products, there's a chance. But the way I understand the plus and the imaginary unit $i$, we have $su(2) +i su(2) = sl_2(\mathbb C)$ (namely, as sum inside the algebra on the right), and consequently the exponentiated Lie group of that is not $SU(2) \times SU(2)$, but $SL_2(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: As for direct sums and products, compare the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/743604/96384.