# Simple example that direct sum of algebra leads to direct product of group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The algebra of the Lorentz group is $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)$  and as such the group is isomorphic to $SU(2) \otimes SU(2)$. Since I'm not a mathematician (just a lousy physicist), is there a simple analogy for this? Alternatively, is there a proof in prose?

Comment: Edit: turned into an answer

Comment: It is neither true that the Lie algebra of the Lorentz group is $\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)$ nor that the Lorentz group is a direct product. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(4)$, so this is Euclidean signature. This only implies that a neighborhood of the identity in $SO(4)$ is isomorphic to a product of two neighborhoods of the identity in $SU(2)$, globally it is only true that $SO(4)\cong (SU(2)\times SU(2))/Z$, wherei $Z$ is a two-element subgroup. There are corresponding statements in Lorentzian signature.

Comment: Also, $\otimes$ usually means *tensor product*, which is something deifferent than the *direct product*, which is usually denoted $\times$.

Also, this here seems highly related to your actual question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/743604/96384

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg yes, I found that question and read the section from Morse theory but I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the exponential map can be thought of as turning addition into multiplication just like the original exponential: $e^{X+Y} = e^X e^Y$.

The only caveat now is we need $X$ and $Y$ to commute for the above formula to hold true. But that is exactly what being a direct sum of Lie algebras gives us. Any element is of the form $X+Y$ with $[X,Y]=0$ so exponentiates to something of the form $e^{X}e^{Y}$.

Edit: after some thought I've realised that there is more complexity that we've brushed under the carpet. The direct product of two Lie groups $G \times H$ does indeed have Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h}$ but there are many Lie groups for the same Lie algebra and we should be more careful about saying "the Lie group". In particular $SO(4)$ is not the same as $SU(2) \times SU(2)$. They are only locally isomorphic.

Thus exponentiating a direct sum does not give us a direct product in general.

Comment: Well that was quite easy after all! Thanks!